# How to clone object and represent it in component?

Tags: angular

I have an object:

```
let root = { id: 1, "children": [
   { id: 2, children: [{}, {}, {}]}
]};
```

I go through every children block in loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let child of root.children">
   <app-block [child]="child"></app-block>
</div>
```

So in `child` variable I have:

```
[
   { id: 2, children: [{}, {}, {}]}
]
```

This data is passed to component `app-block` and represented here.

Issue is how to clone a component with this `child` and modify initial object as:

```
let root = { id: 1, "children": [
       { id: 2, children: [{}, {}, {}]},
       { id: 2, children: [{}, {}, {}]} <--cloned
    ]};
```

Clone without reference to old object?

I have tried to use `<app-wrapper-component [child]="child">` that has:

```
public childRows: any[] = [];
add() { this.childRows.push(...); }
remove() {}
```

Template `app-wrapper-component` is:

```
<div *ngFor="let child of childRows">
    <app-block [child]="child"></app-block>
</div>
```

But this way does not change initial object and don't insert a cloned object to `root` structure.

So, I have reference to `{ id: 2, children: [{}, {}, {}]}` how to find `children[]` element to push here?

Comment: Seems I need to find parent ` "children": []` where clonning object is placed and insert a new object in this array. But how to look it up?

Comment: So, I have reference to `{ id: 2, children: [{}, {}, {}]}` how to find `children` element?

Comment: I think you should also pass the ```root``` data to your child component via binding (e.g. ```[root]="root"```) and perform the clone operation inside that array.

Another option would be to create an ```@Output``` event in the child when it should be cloned. The root component listens to that event and performs the cloning in the root array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communicate with `@Output` from the child component to the parent component in order to pass him the child to be cloned and a related action.

Child template :

```
<button (click)="cloneChild.emit(child)">clone child</button>
```

Child Component :

```
@Output() cloneChild = new EventEmitter();
```

Parent template :

```
<app-child *ngFor="let child of root.children" [child]="child" (cloneChild)="cloneChild($event)"></app-child>
```

Parent Component :

```
cloneChild(child) {
      this.root.children.push(child);
  }
```